# Count No of times a value changed in a table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table like this

```
uid  key   value
---------------
125 'saf'  True
152 'asd'  False
152 'asd'  True
162 'asd' False
162 'asd' False
```

I need to get the number of times a key is changed from above table.

for example for the key 'asd'
output:

```
uid  key   count
---------------
152 'asd'  1
162 'asd'  0
```

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering .  .  . a creation date or id or something.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, your question doesn't really make sense because it implies some sort of ordering of the rows and there is no obvious ordering.  Let me assume that some column has this information (say an auto incremented `id` or creation date).

You can use `lag()` followed by a conditional sum.  In RedShift, I think this looks like:

```
select uid, key,
       sum(case when prev_value is null or prev_value <> value then 1 else 0 end) as num_changes
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by uid, key order by ??) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
group by uid, key;
```

The `??` is the column that specifies the ordering of the rows.